# g++ gives the warning message deleting array in virtual destructor, what does this mean?

Tags: c++, memory, destructor

I have a class Room that inherits from an abstract class MapSite. The destructor for Room looks like this:

```
Room::~Room()
{
  delete[] sides;
}
```

MapSites's destructor is just this:

```
virtual ~MapSite() {}
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
Room::Room() : inventory(new Inventory) 
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    sides[i] == nullptr;
}
```

the private members of room looks like this:

```
private:
  int roomNumber = INVALID_ROOM_NUMBER; // Room number
  MapSite *sides[5]; // Room roof/floor/wall/exits
  std::string name; // Name of room
  std::string description; // Room description
  std::string lookDescription; // Extra description shown on look command
  std::string filename = INVALID_ROOM_FILENAME; // Lua file associated with room
  bool visited = false;
  std::unique_ptr<Inventory> inventory;
```

And I am getting the warning:

```
room.cxx: In destructor ‘virtual Room::~Room()’:
room.cxx:45:12: warning: deleting array ‘((Room*)this)->Room::sides’ [enabled by default]
   delete[] sides;
```

**Could someone please explain to me what this warning means?** And should/how can I suppress it?I couldn't find anything from a quick google search.Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, `sides[i] = nullptr;` not `sides[i] == nullptr;`

Comment: Secondly, you are trying to delete a concrete array. `sides[5]` doesn't need deleting, maybe its elements do.

Comment: @Gluttton sides is an array of size 5 that its elements are pointers to MapSite objects.

Comment: Ugh, I feel stupid now, Thanks! @40two

Comment: `for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) sides[i] == nullptr;` even when written with `=`, is unnecessary. `Room::Room() : sides{}, inventory(new Inventory) {}` is sufficient (or `sides()` in C++03).

Comment: Change `MapSite *sides[5];` to `MapSite **sides;` if you want to manage that array dynamically. `delete[]`'ing it is of course not necessary as you have it declared as a fixed size member array. You might want to `delete` the pointers contained there.

Comment: I certainly agree with @dyp.

Comment: The real problem here is that you should be declaring `std::array<std::unique_ptr<MapSite>, 5> sides;` and removing your destructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general you shouldn't `delete[]` an array declared using the syntax

```
T a[N];
```

where `T` is some type and `N` is some integer.

Consider first what happens if the array is allocated on the stack (automatic storage duration). Then it will automatically be deallocated at the end of its scope, so you shouldn't call `delete` on it.

Now consider what happens if `a` has dynamic storage duration. You can't dynamically allocate the array `a` when it is declared as an array type. Calling `new` gives you a *pointer*, but you can't assign that pointer value to an array variable. So `a` must be a subobject of a dynamically allocated object. But in this case the memory for `a` will be allocated when the complete object is created, and deallocated when the complete object is destroyed. Once again, no need to manually manage the memory for `a`.

On the other hand, it may be that you want to `delete` each *element* of your array `sides`, since each element is itself a pointer. The `delete[]` syntax does *not* do this. You would have to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    delete sides[i];
}
```

Comment: "In general you shouldn't..." implies that there could be some case where it's OK. Pretty sure it's *never* OK to `delete[]` an array that didn't come from `new[]`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I also cannot think of when it would be OK, but since gcc says "enabled by default", I wondered whether there was some case I just wasn't clever enough to see.